# Why is the while loop not looping back once the conditions are not fulfilled?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am coding a program in which it allows the user to enter a year, e.g. 2022 and outputs a suitable message that tells the user whether it is a leap year or not. Within this, there are several 'checks' - i.e. a type  check, a presence check and a length check. To control this I am using a while loop. However, if the initial input  not correct, then the while loop keeps looping, even if the input entered is correct eventually. Additionally, it repeats the same message if the checks are passed. The code is below:

```
  print("Did you know that the last leap year was in 2020?")
    print("To find out if a year is a leap year, use this program")
    year = input("Please enter a year\n")
    pear = str(year)
    valid = False

    while valid == False:
        if pear == "":
            print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
            year = input("Please enter a year\n")
        else:
            if pear.isnumeric() == False:
                print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
                year = input("Please enter a year\n")
                year = str(year)
            else: 
                if len(pear) != 4  : 
                    print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
                    year = input("Please enter a year\n")
                else:
                    year = int(year)
                    sem = str(year)
                    tem = sem.index("0")
                    lem = sem.rindex("0")
                    rem = year%4
                    eem = year%400

                    if tem == 2 and lem == 3:
                        if eem == 0:
                            print(f"{year} is a leap year")
                            valid == True
                        else:
                            print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
                            valid == True
                    else:
                        if rem == 0:
                            print(f"{year} is a leap year")
                            valid == True
                        else:
                            print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
                            valid == True
print("Nice")
```

Comment: Where do you change `valid` to something else than `False`? (you will say: "here: ...", and then I will say: "really?")

Comment: The code had missed lines, the edited version is above.

Comment: Okay, my comment still applies.

Comment: Your variable names are inscrutable, but the root problem is that if *any* of your checks pass, the `valid` flag is set. So it only has to pass one check. Change your logic to count how many checks pass, and check the counter to make sure they all passed. Or, set your `valid` flag to `True` at the beginning of the loop, and set it to `False` when something doesn't pass.

Comment: Your `valid` "reassignment" is actually checking equivalency. Change the `valid == true` ... to `valid = true` if you wish to perform assignment.

Comment: What do you think `valid == True` does?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
print("Did you know that the last leap year was in 2020?")
print("To find out if a year is a leap year, use this program")
year = input("Please enter a year\n")
valid = False

while valid == False:
    if year == "":
        print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
        year = input("Please enter a year\n")
        continue
    if year.isnumeric() == False or len(year) != 4:
        print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
        year = input("Please enter a year\n")
        continue

    # year is a leap year if year can be divided by 4
    # number can be divided by 4 if its last 2 digits can be divided by 4
    last_two_digits = abs(int(year)) % 100
    if (last_two_digits % 4) == 0:
        print(f"{year} is a leap year")
    else:
        print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
    valid = True
print("Nice")
```

While loop was infinite because there was **valid == True** instead of **valid = True**

Comment: Style: `year.isnumeric() == False` can be written as `not year.isnumeric()`. Logic: The program says that 1900 is a leap year. It isn't.